# What is the usage of "like" in the 2 sentences?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, sentence-meaning, as-like

The two sentences below convey different meanings. The first one means no machine at all while the second one means there may be machines but they are another sort of model. I think the usage of *like* is crucial. But I'm not sure what part of speech it is in the two sentences respectively.

1. There were no x-ray machines or body scanners **like** the ones you find at the entrance to the U.S. Capitol and the White House.
2. No x-ray machines or body scanners here were **like** the ones you find at the entrance to the U.S. Capitol and the White House.

Is *like* in the first sentence a preposition meaning "such as", but in the second sentence one meaning "similar to"?

Comment: "Like" here expresses a scalar comparison of equality. It belongs to the word class (POS) **preposition** whose function here is head of the PP "like the ones you find ...", which has the NP "the ones you find ..." as its object. In both cases, "like" is in competition with "similar to". In the first example, "like" may also be in competition with "such as".

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much! So maybe "like" is not the key element differentiating the two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

In the second sentence, "no" roughly means "none of the".

So the subject of that sentence is, "*None of the x-ray machines or body scanners (that are) here*". This means the rest of the sentence will be something that doesn't apply to any of the machines here.

It has nothing to do with "like" or any other word after the subject.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! Could the second sentence be altered to "X-ray machines or body scanners here were not like the ones ..."

Comment: Close: "***The** X-ray machines **and** body scanners here were not like the ones...*"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the first one means literally there are no machines at all. I personally feel both ss means the same.